# what is the best way to share the state outside same component in react

Tags: reactjs, state

I have encountered a problem and I am new to react. I wanted to find what is the best way to share react state outside of the same component for updating input value

```
function async callAjax(makeAjaxRequest){
 //some ajax call
 updateState();
 return false;
}

function updateState() {
   //I want to update state here from component and from outside
```

// component as well i.e call from callAjax function

```
  //I wanted to submit form after state update, Can I pass formRef to
```

//chaining functions to submit or is there any better way?
}

```
export class test extends React.Component<testProps> {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      action: ''
    }

   AjaxRequest = await callAjax(
          this.props.makeAjaxRequest
   );
   updateState();
   render() {
     <form>
      <input type="hidden" value={this.state.action} />
     </form>
   }
}
```

I have done research around this found some like react sharedContext(useContext) but useContext is mostly used between different components for sharing data but I wanted inside single component. Can anyone help find best way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want state outside the component?

Comment: @SelvaS - Depending on the ajax call made I want to update input value. Other than state is there any other way?

Comment: You can pass the value as Props to the component and update it in `useEffect` or `ComponentDidMount`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't update the state of a component outside of the component as this may lead to problems. If you must have `updateState` outside of the component I think you can add callback which will be run when needed.

```
function async callAjax(makeAjaxRequest, stateCallback ){
   updateState( stateCallback );
   return false;
}

function updateState( stateCallback ) {
   const newValue = 123
   stateCallback( newValue )
}

export class Test extends React.Component<TestProps> {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         action: ''
      }
   }
   
   AjaxRequest = await callAjax(
      this.props.makeAjaxRequest,
      ( newValue ) => this.setState( newValue )
   );
   
   render() {
      <form>
         <input type="hidden" value={this.state.action} />
      </form>
   }
}
```

You can also find concept of Redux interesting.

Comment: Yeah, Redux solves the problem. But for a single component, we don't need redux at all. He can pass the value as prop if he updates from outside and for inside scenario, he can directly update the state.